# how can I make the executable search for the .dll binary with find_package

Tags: c++, dll, cmake

I am now writing a dynamic library in Windows with cmake and C++. I export the library with the following commands:

```
write_basic_package_version_file( 
         "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${libName}ConfigVersion.cmake"
          VERSION ${version}
          COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion
          )

configure_package_config_file(${input} ${output}
                     INSTALL_DESTINATION "${config_install}"
                      PATH_VARS target_export_name_local target_head_dir
                      )     

install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${libName}Config.cmake"  
                "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${libName}ConfigVersion.cmake"
             DESTINATION "${config_install}")
install(EXPORT ${libName}
                    NAMESPACE "" 
                    DESTINATION  ${config_install})
```

By doing so, I can have the library configuration files as well. In my case, I will have `libConfig.cmake lib.cmake lib-debug.cmake lib-release.cmake`

Suppose now I have an application that will use this dynamic library, I can use `find_package` to to import the library in my application project. Everything goes on fine. But when I create the executable `exe.exe`, and try to run it. Then, I will have the following error message:

```
The program cannot start because lib.dll cannot be found ...
```

Then now I have two solutions: the first one is to copy the lib.dll to the output folder of the application project. There is a property called `IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG` related to the imported library target, and I can know the location of the dll and then perform the coping.

The second solution is to make sure that when running the application, it will also search for the folder that contains the lib.dll. However, I do not know how to do it in CMake. Any ideas?

By the way, do you have other solutions to this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing seems more related to binary distribution than the original scope of CMake. When releasing the application for 3rd party users, you either distribute it in a way that it embeds and find all the libraries, or you could state that a library is an explicit requirement of your application, and let the user install it (not so common in Windows as I remember it).

Now, when you are facing this problem on your development environment, you do not need to complicate things too much. I would say there are 2 good alternatives:

### Static library approach

On Windows environment (and I imagine most other OSes), if you are intentionally using shared libraries (i.e., *DLL* files), it more or less means that you want to **share the library** file among several applications using it.
If this assumption holds true, the idea of copying the dll in each application folder can seem to be contradictory. If you are actually okay to embed one copy of the library binaries with each application using it, why not statically link the application to it ? It could reduce the total space used (because the linker will embed the object code only for the functions that are actually used, whereas if you copy the *DLL* all the object code is obviously coming with the copy).

You can set CMake variable [`BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.html#variable:BUILD_SHARED_LIBS) to `OFF` in the CMake project compiling your library to generate a static library. When you use such a static library, the library is needed at link time, but not at runtime.

### Actually sharing code

Then, on the other hand, you potentially want to actually share the dll file among several applications. A good way to control that in Windows environment is to make sure that the path to your *DLL* file is found in the `PATH` environment variable of Windows.

There are two obvious way to do that:

- Install your library DLL in a path already present in the `PATH` variable.
- Add the library install directory to the `PATH` variable.